# Fetch count cloudwatch log using node js for a specific date range

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Howto get the count ?, i have check the query in cloud watch Insights i got output , can any one help me

```
async function main(){
    const logGroupName = '/aws/apprunner/<Name of your Log Group>';
    const timestamp = new Date();
    let queryCount = `stats count() as total`;
    const params = {
        startTime: '1675103400000',
        endTime: '1675189799000',
        queryString: queryCount,
        logGroupName: logGroupName
      };

      // 1. Start the query. When we start a query, this returns a queryId for us to use on our next step.
    const data = await cloudWatchLogs.startQuery(params).promise();
    const { queryId } = data;
    console.debug('query id', queryId);
   

    // 2. Send Insight query to CloudwatchLogs
    const insightData = await cloudWatchLogs.getQueryResults({ queryId })
        .promise();
        console.log(insightData);
    return ;
}

main();
```

```
o/p: {
  results: [],
  statistics: { recordsMatched: 0, recordsScanned: 0, bytesScanned: 0 },
  status: 'Running'
}
```

try to get the count from result from above code i have posted

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zenoyu/f63799a9079a5df376d5daf3cea27be4 - you need to repeatedly call `getQueryResults` until the `status` is e.g. `"Complete"` instead of `"Running"``.

Comment: Hi Thanks for input I'm getting total value as response  from cloud watch API,  how to get only the value from the cloud watch response 
Example: 
[
        {
            "field": "message.requestBody.data.params.transaction_id",
            "value": "1005439392"
        },
        {
            "field": "@ptr",
            "value": "CqMBCmYKYjM1MjY4MDE5MTY2MDovYXdzL2FwcHJ1bm5lci9yZi1tMi1wcm9kLW1pZGRsZXdhcmUtYXBpLzgzYTg5YjNlZGE4MDQzMzc5NWMzYjhmNDYyYjI1ZmQzL2FwcGxpY2F0aW9uEAYSNxoYAgY7a3eOAAAAAKs4ZLEABj4yp7AAAAHiIAEo/pr5+uIwMNyL/vriMDgYQNCKAUjAvQFQ5HgYABAWGAE="
        }
    ]